# Opaque overlay becomes transparent when fading out both video tracks in Sony Vegas

Tags: vegas-pro

The original problem I had was to put an overlay (static image) on a video track. All guides/tutorials I found does this by putting the image into a separate video track. I would prefer attaching the image to the actually video clip instead, but fair enough, it works.

However, when I try to fade out the video + overlay, they do this at different "pace". The video is recorded from gameplay, and I want to cover the chatbox with a black image. It works fine, and I can't see through the image at all. But when I fade out the video track and the image, I can pause in the fading and actually see the chat box. This is extremely frustrating, and not at all what I want of course.

I have tried different things, fading out by dragging the right corner, and a composite level envelope, but it doesn't help. It doesn't matter if it transitions into another video clip or to black, same problem occurs anyway.

Here is an example of how it looks:

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior for fading two video tracks.  Video tracks are blended in order to build up what you see as an end result.  When you make the image mask (the overlay) for the chat pain start fading to transparent, it allows the images underneath to be seen.  So if it is at 70% transparent, it lets through 30% of the underlying layers, which in turn is letting through 30% of the layer under it.

To get around this, you need to fade the combined video rather than the individual videos.  The easiest way to do this in your case is going to be to use parent/child compositing relationships.  By telling Vegas that the two clips are related and should have effects applied to both, it should allow you to have an effect applied to the sum total of both tracks instead of needing to apply it to both individually.

Sony actually already has a pretty nice write up on the feature available [here](http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/parent_child_track_relationship).

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I really appreciate it. However, I can't get it to work anyway. Even though I make it a Compositing Child, it still creates the fade for the individual clips in the tracks. Doesn't matter if I select track 1, track 2, or the side of track 1 which then selects the parent and all the childs. I guess the whole idea with creating parent/child is that it can be treated as "one clip", which would solve my problem. But I can't created the fade for the united tracks.

Comment: What I want is the effect to be the same as if I did a workaround and created new projects for each clip with overlay and rendered it. Of course, I don't want to create projects just to merge the overlay into a clip and then import the re-encoded file into my "real" project file.

Comment: Yeah, that kind of sub clip thing can be done in most professional editors but I was surprised that Vegas limits you to a single timeline.  I'll try giving the compositing thing a try and see if I can get it to work later, but I've been in prep mode for a conference this weekend so time has been limited.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is by creating a solid colour (black) clip, placing it above the two clips and fading it in. Remove the fades from the other two clips when you do this.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem and finally figured out a solution.

My project consists of one main video track with several tracks of generated media above it (to obscure aspects of the video track that I don't want to see with colored boxes).

Then above all of that I have a secondary video track to which I occasionally want to fade in and out of from the main video track.

The problem is that when I set the fades, the generated media fades out too and what it's obscuring is briefly visible during the transition.  Or if I don't use a fade on the generated media, the bars are visible and then abruptly disappear during the transition.

The solution was to add a new video track with a generated media object black background beneath the secondary video track.  Then whenever I fade in to or out of the secondary video, I also add the same fade to the black object, and the primary video and all of its generated media fade in/out evenly with each other (i.e., the obscured content is not visible during the transition).

Thanks,
Steven